# SPSS: how to loop and concatenate values to create file

Tags: loops, spss

Hi I have a syntax file and I want to create several `.sav` files

```
for 87 to 95
  for 1 to 12
    FILE HANDLE EPA/NAME='C:\Users\gma\Downloads/pub0187.prn'/LRECL=138.
    DATA LIST FILE=EPA/
     STATES_PROV  001 - 007
     ...          .....
     VARIABLE LABELS
     ...
     MISSING VALUES
     ....

    SAVE OUTFILE='C:\Users\gma\Downloads/epa0187.sav'.
  end
end
```

Output file

```
epa0187.sav
epa0287.sav
epa0387.sav
...
epa0188.sav
...
epa0189.sav
...
epa1295.sav
```

Input file

```
pub0187.prn
pub0287.prn
...
pub0188.prn
...
pub0189.prn
...
pub1295.prn
```

So in other words I want to create a `.sav` file for each month from January 1987 up to December 1995.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a macro loop in standard Statistics syntax, but here is a solution using Python code within Statistics.  Note that the indentations are important.

```
begin program.
import spss

for year in range(87, 96):  # note stop is one beyond
    for month in range(1, 13):  # one beyond
        spss.Submit(r"""FILE HANDLE EPA
/NAME='C:\Users\gma\Downloads/pub%(month)s%(year)s.prn'/LRECL=138.
DATA LIST FILE=EPA/
 STATES_PROV  001 - 007
 ...          .....
 VARIABLE LABELS
 ...
 MISSING VALUES
 ....

SAVE OUTFILE='C:\Users\gma\Downloads/epa%(month)s%(year)s.sav'.""" % locals())
end program.
```

Comment: note that the file names have a two digit number for all months, so `month` needs to be 01, 02 ... instead of  1, 2, 3 ...

Comment: to get that, change the formats for the month parts like this: %(month)02d  instead of %(month)s